# spring rest exception in service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am implementing a spring rest application as a maven multi module project. controllers in web, service and dao as layers.

I am having issues to find the exact cause and stack trace for any exception in service layer. I am not using any try catch block in the service methods. Instead, I am just throwing an exception. Now when a null pointer exception is raised, the global exception handler is finding the exception. It says null, but does not provide any stack trace.

Do I need to use try catch blocks? If yes, I will have these blocks all over the service methods.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Show your global exception handler. I assume you're not showing the stacktrace there if it's not being shown.

Comment: @ExceptionHandler({ Exception.class })
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> handleAnyException(Exception e) {
 logger.error("Error: " + e.getMessage());
 logger.error("Error [cause]: " + e.getCause());
}

Comment: One more thing. Invocation target exception is called. I am not finding the stacktrace there too.

Comment: Are you just trying to find the cause of the nullpointer? For now why don't you just remove the exceptionhandler and then you can view the full stacktrace? Also generally throwing/catching nullpointers in bad programming practice.  You should be programming defensively and throwing specific runtime errors in the event of unexpected nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception handler isn't displaying the stacktrace because you're not telling it to. Your code is bad and broken.

```
logger.error("Error: " + e.getMessage());
logger.error("Error [cause]: " + e.getCause());
```

Using `getMessage()` to see what exception you're having is useless. A `NullPointerException` returns as its message the String `"null"`, which doesn't help you solve problems one bit. Logging the cause like that will call the `toString()` method of `cause` which won't be helpful either.

The only way to deal with exceptions is:

```
logger.error("Error", e);
```

This will log the stacktrace properly, including any causes (your code didn't even consider that a cause can also have a cause). You can use a custom message instead of "Error", but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I never realized that there is a difference between the below.
logger.error("Error: " + e);
logger.error("Error: ", e);

String concatenation is not working, which was my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ExceptionHandler.
[Here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exceptionhandler-example/) you'll find some examples and see that dont need to modify your current code. Remember to use a Logger or put a System.out.printLn() to see the stacktrace of the exception.
Also maybe you have to consider debug your method to see waht parameter or method is givin a null value.

Comment: i am doing what is mentioned in the example. i find getcause to be null pointer exception. when i log the message it says just null with no other information. in eclipse if i inspect, the getcause has infinite number of getcause 's.

Comment: mmmm maybe you are using e.getMessage(), instead of it you have to put e.printStackTrace()  or print just e like object, this will print the exception with the class names and methods that throw it.

Comment: Put this on your code: { logger.error("Error: " , e); }

Comment: String concatenation was the issue on my side. I had to use comma. Thanks for the inputs.